# $g$ in $L^1([0,1])$ and $h$ a continuous strictly increasing function on [0, 1] with h(0) > 0. If $\int_0^1gh^n = 0$ for $n=1,2,...$, then g = 0 a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on this problem:

Let $g$ in $L^1([0,1], m)$ (Lebesgue measure) and $h$ a continuous strictly increasing function on [0, 1] with $h(0) > 0$. If
$$\forall n=1,2,...: \int_0^1gh^n = 0,$$
prove that $g = 0$ a.e.

My attempt:

The first thing I notice is that I can divide $h$ by any constant and the equation still holds, so pick any $0\leq a \leq 1$, and let $h_a = h/h(a)$, $\int_0^1gh_a^n = 0$. Since $h_a(a) = 1$ and it is strictly increasing, I have for any $n$,
$$|\int_0^agh_a^n| \leq ||g||_1.$$
By assuming $g$ is not the 0 function, I can find an $a$ such that $\int_a^1 g \neq 0$. I then want to say the $(a, 1)$ part becomes very large when $n$ increases, and that it is impossible to use the left part to cancel out. However I am not sure if this is true or how to prove it, by doing this I can only show that $g$ must alternate between positive and negative when approaching 1.

I think my approach could be wrong because I have no idea how to use the continuity condition, and it seems just fine if $h(0) = 0$. Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be respectively the values of $h$ at $0$ and $1$.
For any continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, by Stone-Weierstrass, there is a sequence of polynomials $(P_n)$ defined on the inteveral $[a,b]$ such that $P_n$ converges uniformly to $f \circ h^{-1}$ . Thus, $P_n \circ h$ converges uniformly to $f$. Thus, $ \int_0^1 g(P_n \circ h)$ converges to $ \int_0^1 gf$. In otherwords, $ \int_0^1 gf=0$ for all $f$ continuous. Hence, $g=0$ a.s.

Comment: Just want to make sure I completely understand, the convergence of the integral follows from dominated convergence theorem since g is L1 right? And does it matter whether h(0) > 0 or not?

Comment: @KerwinYi Yes, the convergence of integrals follows from dominated convergence and the fact that $g \in L^1$. Nonetheless, you can even prove that $$\left| \int g P_n\circ h - \int gf \right| \le \| g\|_{L^1} \| P_n \circ h -f\|_{\infty}.$$

Comment: Thank you! And did you use the condition h(0) > 0 anywhere? It seemed to me that all we need is a continuous inverse of h, and that what h takes at 0 and 1 doesn't matter?