# Prove or disprove: If $\int_0^1f(t)t^{2n+1}dt=0$ for each integer $n\geq 0$, then $f=0$ on $[0 ,1]$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

**The Problem**: Prove or disprove: if $\int_0^1f(t)t^{2n+1}dt=0$ for each integer $n\geq 0$, then $f=0$ on $[0 ,1]$. $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

And, a follow-up: What if "$n\geq0$" is replaced by "$n\geq1$"?

My conjecture is that $f=0$ on $[0, 1]$ in both cases.

**My Attempt**: Let $I_1$ be the union of all the intervals in $[0, 1]$ such that $f(x)>0$, and let $I_2$ be the union of all the intervals in $[0, 1]$ such that $f(x)<0$. Then we must have $$\int_{I_1}f(t)t^{2n+1}dt=-\int_{I_2}f(t)t^{2n+1}dt\quad(*)$$ for all $n\geq0$. (or $\geq1$)

As $n\to\infty$, the integrals on both sides of the equation $(*)$ will get smaller. Since $f(x)$ does not change and $t^{2n+1}$ changes unevenly, my intuition tells me that $(*)$  will fail to hold when $n$ becomes large enough; but I am unable to show that.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486269/g-in-l10-1-and-h-a-continuous-strictly-increasing-function-on-0-1/4486297#4486297 . You just have to choose the right $g$ and $h$.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen I appreciate the reference! But "In other words, $\int_0^1gf=0$ for all $f$ continuous" is a bit too abrupt for me. How exactly do you conclude that $\int_0^1g(P_n\circ h)\to0$?

Comment: @Grayson: You're welcome. It's because based on the hypothesis, $$\int_0^1 g(x)P(h(x))\mathrm{d}x =0$$ for all polynomial $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: This question **is not** a duplicate of the linked question. Here we only know that $f$ is orthogonal to every *odd* polynomial. Also: what do we know in advance about $f$? Continuity? Integrability? Square-integrability?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Hi Jack: $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ here is continuous, which implies integrability. It is now edited.

Comment: In such a case you may just exploit Weierstrass approximation theorem. You have that $f(\sqrt{x})$ is continuous and orthogonal to every (non-constant) polynomial, hence it is zero.

Comment: See also `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Müntz–Szász_theorem`

Comment: Unfortunately, due to a lack of foundation I cannot say I quite follow either of the alternative approaches, but I appreciate the extra help!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : This is surely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is correct. Let us consider $g(t)=f(\sqrt{t})$, which is continuous over $[0,1]$.
 In the first case, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1} g(t) t^n \,dt \stackrel{t\mapsto x^2}{=} 2\int_{0}^{1}f(x) x^{2n+1}\,dx = 0 \tag{1}$$
so $g$ is orthogonal to every polynomial. By the density of polynomials among the $C^0([0,1])$ functions we have that $g$ is orthogonal to itself, hence $g\equiv 0$ and $f\equiv 0$ as well.

In the second case (i.e. when $(1)$ holds only for $n\geq 1$) we have that $g(t)$ is orthogonal to every polynomial of the form $t\cdot p(t)$. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem we have that $g(t)$ is orthogonal to every function of the form
$$ l_m(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} mt &\text{if}& 0\leq t \leq \frac{1}{m}\\ 1 &\text{if}& \frac{1}{m}\leq t\leq 1\end{array}\right.\quad\text{for some }m\in\mathbb{N}^+$$
since $l_m(t)/t$ is continuous over $[0,1]$. By the dominated/monotone convergence theorem
$$ \int_{0}^{1} g(t)\,dt = \lim_{m\to +\infty} \int_{0}^{1} g(t) l_m(t)\,dt = 0 $$
so $g$ is orthogonal to the constant $1$ and we fall back into the previous case.

As pointed out in the comments, the entire exercise is a simple corollary of the [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem), since
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2n+1}\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2n+1} $$
are both divergent.